# How to turn off SpeedStep in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, speedstep

I have an Asus N53SV  laptop with Windows 7 64-bit. I need to calibrate profiler in NetBeans, and to do that I need to disable functions that lower the CPU frequency in my laptop. I believe it's called Intel SpeedStep Technology.

I have absolutely no option in BIOS regarding power saving frequency settings. Basically all I can change is the boot order. (I have the latest BIOS installed) I have tried changing the power plan to high performance, and setting CPU options in it to 100%, but according to CPU-Z, nothing happened. So how to turn it off? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Open the Power Options(press [image] + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `powercfg.cpl`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>), follow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to advanced power options for your power profile and change both minimum and maximum CPU state to 100%. This should ensure that the processor will never step down to a power frequency.

[image]

Edit: you may need to also set the cooling policy to "active" to ensure that heat issues aren't slowing you down. See this question for additional info: [What regulates Intel SpeedStep CPU throttling? Can I get some control of this on Windows7?](https://superuser.com/questions/183508/what-regulates-intel-speedstep-cpu-throttling-can-i-get-some-control-of-this-on?rq=1)

Comment: I did this, that's what I meant by "have tried changing the power plan to high performance, and setting CPU options in it to 100%"
Didn't help..

Comment: Is speedstep noticeably affecting the results of the profiling?